# Quirks Mode Dilemna

Tags: html, quirks-mode

I am trying to write a js widget which will displayed on diverse websites. 
The problem is that many times, the widget will be used on websites which will not provide proper doctype declarations and hence will render the pages in quirksmode.
When the widget is rendered in quirksmode,the UI breaks up. 
How do i go about writing HTML that works same in both quirks mode as well as in standards mode

Comment: All I can suggest is looking up the consistencies between modes. Sorry if it is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control what mode the host site uses, but you may be able to use an `iframe` in which to render your widget.

Comment: Yes, but that can be difficult depending on what you want to do.